# How can I make the main thread waiting for some seconds and then call a method?

Tags: objective-c, c

I'm very new in Objective C programming and I started to program a simple exercise. 
I want my `main()` to call a method from a class and from that method to use performSelector:(SEL) withObject:afterDelay.
The problem is that it doesn't call the method, and it doesn't delay either. 
//main

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
...
    State * state = [[State alloc] init];
    [state startTimer];
   ...
}
```

//State.m

```
-(void)complete{
    NSLog(@"The door is Open (OPENING ==> OPEN)");
    [door setState:[door openState]];
}

-(void)startTimer{
    NSLog(@"The timer has started on Opening state");
//    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30 target:self selector:@selector(complete) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
//    [timer retain];
//    [timer fire];
//    [timer release];
    [self performSelector: @selector(complete) withObject:nil afterDelay:30];
}
```

I have modified a little the code, but is the same. It's not the problem in the rest of the code, but in the `startTimer()` method because it doesn't call the `complete()` method. If I use the NSThread (which is commented out) it will call it but still no delay. I have looked all over the places and I saw that for my purposes this is the best solution, but is not working for me. 
To get an idea of what it has to do the program, the state has to remain for 30 seconds on "OPENING" and then `complete` and set it to OPEN state.

Comment: [state startTimer]; --- what is the code after this line of statement...

Comment: In main() it's the last line...

Comment: then your process will be terminated before required things to happen ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[performSelector:(SEL) withObject:afterDelay](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-performSelector_withObject_afterDelay_) requires you to be using a [run loop](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW1).  In a normal application, the run loop is set up and runs automatically.  In a command line program (such as yours) you would need to set up and run the run loop yourself.  Example code [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW5).

However, if you just want to delay your program for a bit and don't need to be doing anything else, it's simpler just to use the [sleep()](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/sleep.3.html) function.

Comment: @Adrian: The run loop is created for you but you need to run it yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, but I still don't fully get it. Doesn't the run loop from my main start when I run the whole program? And doesn't my performSelector:... use that run loop? THank you again!

Comment: No, it doesn't start unless you run it.  Please read the link I provided to the Apple documentation on run loops. It's not that hard to make a run loop run, you basically need to call the right function on NSRunLoop.

Comment: @Girish: He's not blocking the event loop, he doesn't *have* an event loop.

Comment: @JeremyP you are right ... I am sure app will be terminated ... he better use performSelector without delay in this case.

Answer (score 1):

performSelector will be invoked on the present run loop context(call insertion run loop context). If the run loop context is no more active when invocation has to happen things will not work.

Make sure that your calling run loop of calling thread is active. ---- may be I can understand better if you show more code from your main function.

Why thread solution is worked of you -- when you create thread it is get executed by the process --- so irrespective of the calling run loop secondary thread will be called in process scope.

Comment: but when it gets to my startTimer() method isn't the run loop context active? so why doesn't just waits the seconds and then call the method it has to? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: run loop has to be active when "complete" function has to be invoked by the runloop, you have registered for the invocation.